# Terminal Command for Opening a New Finder Window

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript

I would like a terminal command to open a "new" window in addition to any I already have open (preferably the downloads folder).

Running "open ." will only open if there are no other Finder windows open.

Is there a way to do this with the terminal, or if not with AppleScript?

Comment: You can use `osascript` to run an AppleScript telling the Finder to open a new Finder window - see the Finder’s scripting dictionary for its classes and commands.

Comment: `open .` _should_ open a Finder window irrespective of whether there are other Finder windows open.  The period ("`.`") is shell shorthand for the current working directory, and most shells will expand it to the full path, e.g. `/Users/CK/some/folder`, which is the actual argument sent to the `open` command, and thus the path to which a Finder window should appear (if a Finder window to that path already exists, then that window is brought to the front).  If this is not happening for you, then something is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open new Finder (or any other application) window from terminal/bash shell then use -n flag ("Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running"):

```
open -n .
```

For opening new Finder window in downloads:

```
open -n ~/Downloads
```

Comment: If it solved your problem then please mark it as answered.

Comment: If Finder is not running, then `open -n ~/Downloads` outputs: `The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x600002198d20 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=162 "Unknown error: 162" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}`